# window.blur triggered in IE7 and IE8 when clicking on an image

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, window, internet-explorer-7, blur

In Internet Explorer 7 and 8, but not in 9 and newer, clicking on a div which contains an image on a website, triggers the `window.blur` event. But this is wrong.

However, this is very disfunctional, because we use this method to find out if the user leaves the website (focus is on another window).

Any idea on how to workaround this problem?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @Poornima Unfortunately, _jsfiddle_ does not even *work* with IE7 or IE8... but I solved the problem by now.

Comment: Yes, but if you include your code either in a fiddle or in the question, it will help us reproduce the issue and make some suggestions. Great its solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking `document.hasFocus()` as a first thing in the `window.blur` callback. If it gets triggered wrongly, at least the document does still has focus.

The problem was probably due to using HTML 5 tags such as `article` and `section` which confused the old IEs.